# Random Variables and Probability

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

For each of the conditions (a)-(d) below, give examples of random variables that satisfy the condition, and justify. If no such random variables exist, say so and provide justification.

```
a) Random variables X, Y such that Var (X + Y ) < Var X + Var Y
b) Random variables X, Y such that E(X|Y = y) > E(X) for all y
c) Independent random variables X, Y such that X+Y/Sqrt(2) has the same pdf 
   as X
d) Random variables Xi that are i.i.d, with mean and variance equal to 1, 
   such that P( Summation of Xi > 2n, for i=1 to n)  tends to 0.5 as n tends 
   to become infinite
```

I have solved (a) and it would be true for negative covariance. How to solve the rest. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Image not visible.

Comment: b) is not possible since it implies $EX>EX$. For c) take i.i.d. standard normal.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: How for b) EX>EX and for c) what u mean by take iid standard normal... can you show the working?

Comment: Not allowed to embed image.

Comment: In that case you will have to type out the entire question.

Comment: typed. Could you show the working for b and c. It will help me visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) says $EXI_{Y=y} >EX P\{Y=y\}$ in the disecrete case. Summing over $y$ we get $EX>EX$ In general case use the fact that $E(EX|Y))=EX$ to get the contradiction $EX >EX$. So b) is not possible. For c) take $X,Y$ i.i.d. standard normal and use the fact that characteristic function of standard normal distribution is $e^{-t^{2}/2}$. Using this you can easily check that $\frac {X+Y} {\sqrt 2}$ also has the same characteristic function. [$Ee^{it\frac {X+Y} {\sqrt 2}}=Ee^{it\frac X {\sqrt 2}}Ee^{it\frac Y {\sqrt 2}}=e^{-t^{2}/4}e^{-t^{2}/4}=e^{-t^{2}/2}$].

d) is not possible by SLLN: since $\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \to 1$ almost surely the limit is necessarily $0$.

Comment: Not sure of c) do we need to use e−t2/2 separately for X and Y and then add it and divide by root(2). How should I prove it.

Comment: @Robo4.4 I have added one more step to the answer. The first equality is by independence. In the second equality I have replaced $t$ by $t/\sqrt 2$ in the gaussian characteristic function.

Comment: In the second equality you mean to say you have replaced X by t/root(2)?

Comment: @Robo4.4 Write down the  formula  $Ee^{itx}=e^{-t^{2}/2}$ valid for all $t$ and replace $t$ by $t/\sqrt 2$.